# Whose Fourier series are we finding?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose we evaluate the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ from the function $x^2$ and then find the Fourier series. Whose Fourier series is it?

Is it the Fourier series of the function given by

$f(x)=x^2, x\in[-π,π]$

or,

$f(x)=x^2,x\in(-π,π]$,
$f(x+2π)=f(x)$?

Comment: The expression $x^2$ does not define a function until you specify a domain.   Did you have any particular domain in mind?

Comment: This is a matter of semantics. I wish to know whose Fourier series we call it. The function restricted on an interval $[-L,L]$ or the periodic function on the entire real line.

Comment: It's more than a matter of semantics. You would get different answers depending on whether you chose the domain $[-\pi,\pi]$ (the conventional choice) or the domain $[0,2\pi]$ (a less popular but quite nice choice for some situations) or some other domain. There will be no ambiguity for a function which is already given by a $2\pi$-periodic function, which your second formula specifies. But for a nonperiodic function, the question really does not make sense if the domain is not specified in advance.

Comment: No no. I have a fixed choice of the interval. What I don't know is if I should refer to the series as the Fourier series of the function restricted only to that interval or the one that after restricting to that interval, we extend by letting it have a period equal to $2π$ or $2L$ etc.

Comment: Well then, since you have a fixed choice of the interval, let me repeat my question: What particular domain do you have in mind?

Comment: $[-π,π]$ would be fine

Answer (score 2):

A Fourier series on $[-\pi,\pi]$ can either be viewed as approximating a function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with no periodicity assumed, or else as a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$, or else as a function on the unit circle. The choice is entirely up to you; they are equivalent. What do you want the domain of your function to be?

So if we compute the Fourier coefficients of a non-periodic function such as $x^2$, then according to our three choices, the resulting Fourier series can either be viewed as approximating the function $x^2$ restricted to $[-L,L]$, or it can be viewed as approximating the function

$$
x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\dotsc\\
x^2 & x\in[-L,L]\\
(x-L)^2 & [L,2L]\\
(x-2L)^2 & [2L,3L]\\
\dots
\end{cases}
$$
on all of $\mathbb{R}$, or else it can be $e^{\pi i\theta/L}\mapsto\theta^2$ on the unit circle.

A Fourier series is a sum of periodic functions, so it is always periodic. It can never converge in any sense to a non-periodic function outside of the domain of periodicity. Instead it will converge to the piecewise function you get by forcing the function to be periodic by repeating the output from the fundamental domain.

Comment: Exactly this. I had conflicting ideas about the Fourier series. I thought "I can approximate a function in $[-L,L]$; but then again it works for periodic ones as well; so whose Fourier series are we going to call it exactly?"

Comment: Wait, so it can be of either one of them? A non-periodic function can have a Fourier series as well?

Comment: @HritRoy yes. Let me edit to clarify.

Comment: @HritRoy is it clear now? A Fourier series is always periodic, so it will never converge in any sense to a non-periodic function outside of the domain of periodicity. Instead it will converge to the piecewise function you get by forcing the function to be periodic by repeating the output from the fundamental domain.

Comment: Seems clear to me. But what do we _call_ the Fourier series? _Whose_ Fourier series do we call it? The periodic one, non-periodic one or either one?

Comment: @HritRoy We call it the Fourier series for $x^2$.

Comment: Without mentioning a domain?

Comment: @HritRoy if the domain is clear from context (which it usually will be), then you do not need to mention it. Otherwise, yes, mention it.

Comment: My question is, can this domain we are talking about right now be $[-π,π]$ instead of $ℝ$?

Comment: @HritRoy yes, you have three choices for the domain, one of which is $[-\pi,\pi].$

Comment: That was my question. If I can call it the Fourier series of $f(x), x\in$[-π,π]$. The answer seems to be 'yes'.

Comment: My only hesitation is in your original question, you give it as $f(x)=x^2,$ $x\in[-\pi,\pi],$ $f(x)=f(x+2\pi).$ It is very strange to specify the periodicity when there are no points $x$ such that $x$ and $x+2\pi$ are both in the domain $(-\pi,\pi].$ I would leave that off. The equation $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ is undefined.

Comment: Also, I'll add that it would seem *inappropriate* to specify the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But I meant that the domain is the real line and the values outside $[-π,π]$ are given by the periodicity of $f$.

Comment: What would be a better way of putting it?

Comment: @LeeMosher it is common in engineering or signal processing to compute the Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ on $[-L,L]$ and call it the “sawtooth waveform”, implying a domain of $\mathbb{R}$. Does this usage bother you?

Comment: @HritRoy Ok I see what you mean. But I don't like the way you wrote it. Use a piecewise function notation.

Comment: No, it does not bother me. It's just that I don't know the conventions from engineering or signal processing. And in all of my comments, I was attempting to point out that from a pure mathematical point of view one often has the responsibility of removing any ambiguity oneself.

Comment: @LeeMosher From a mathematical point of view, the best thing to say is that $f$ is a function on $S^1$ and the Fourier coefficients are a function on the dual group, $\mathbb{Z}$. But I fear we'll lose our audience if we go that root :)

Comment: @LeeMosher What is so inappropriate about it?

Comment: @HritRoy mathematically speaking, a nonperiodic function like $x^2$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ induces many different functions on the various translates of the domain. So the choice of a restricted/periodic function is not well-defined. In practice however we may sometimes identify a “best” translate, eg the one centered at $0$.